# Force MPMoviePlayer Youtube video

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to open a mpmovieplayer when the webview is finish loading. The problem is the MPMoviePlayer opens and close and gives me this error:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

I'm using following code which i've found by searching on the internet. Why wont it play the youtube video?

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {

    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/AhE5dsO8xF4"];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
    [mp.moviePlayer play];


}
```